# ERROR while ingegrating MongoDB with Django on windows

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, djongo

I am trying to integrate MongoDB and Django. but when i run the code `python manage.py runmigrations app_name` i am getting the error:

> File "C:\Users\Gourav\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 126, in load_backend
> raise ImproperlyConfigured(
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
> 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

and `utils.py` line 119 to 136 code looks like;

```
builtin_backends = [
    name
    for _, name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(django.db.backends.__path__)
    if ispkg and name not in {"base", "dummy"}
]
if backend_name not in ["django.db.backends.%s" % b for b in builtin_backends]:
    backend_reprs = map(repr, sorted(builtin_backends))
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
        "%r isn't an available database backend or couldn't be "
        "imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the "
        "built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX "
        "is one of:\n"
        "    %s" % (backend_name, ", ".join(backend_reprs))
    ) from e_user
else:
    # If there's some other error, this must be an error in Django
    raise
```

every required directories is already installed in my virtual environment. `pip list` gives following result;

```
asgiref            3.5.2
Django             4.0.5
django-mongoengine 0.5.4
djongo             1.3.6
dnspython          2.2.1
mongoengine        0.24.1
Pillow             9.1.1
pip                22.1.2
psycopg2           2.9.3
pymongo            4.1.1
python-snappy      0.6.1
setuptools         62.1.0
sqlparse           0.2.4
tzdata             2022.1
wheel              0.37.1
winkerberos        0.9.0
```

Kindly looking for help to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the new version of pymongo (4.0 from 29.11.2021) which is not supported by Djongo 1.3.6. we need to install pymongo 3.12.1.

follow these steps;

```
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo==3.12.3
```

It will save your time. it took me more than 24 hours to figure it out.